# Big O of multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, computational-complexity

Can anyone help me?

This is from my abstract algebra/Number theory book.

Show that given integers $n_1,n_2.......,n_k $ with each $n_i > 1$, we can
compute the product $n := n_1 *n_2*........n_k$ in time **$O(len(n)^2)$**.

I know $len(n) \leq len(n_1)+.....+len(n_k)$
Hence, I was thinking worst run time would be $O(len(n_1)*len(n_2)*.....*len(n_5))$       $\quad$ #just guessing here.

Any hint:

Thanks

Comment: if we have $n*n*n* ....*n$ (assume that the number of n is k times) then we have $n^k$ as worst time running time. this is one thing, if you multiply two integer numbers, then the algorithm that do the multiplication has two loops as I remember, therefore the running time of worst case is $O(n^2)$ which is to multiply each number with all other number (which we assume has length of n).

Comment: Does your text specify the time complexity of the multiplication of two numbers $n$ and $m$ with lengths $len(n)$ and $len(m)$?

Comment: Book says:  two numbers n and m with len(n) and len(m) length respectively when multiplied gives c that will have atmost length (len(n)+len(m)) and may be computed in O(len(n)*len(m))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an inductive argument.

For the base case, consider just $n_1$ and $n_2$. For the product $n = n_1 \cdot n_2$, the time complexity for the multiplication is,
$$len(n_1)\cdot len(n_2) \leq len(n) \cdot len(n) = len(n)^2$$

so it is $O(len(n)^2)$.

Now suppose that $n = n_1 \cdot \dots \cdot n_k$ has complexity $O(len(n)^2)$. We will show that the time complexity of $n' = n_1 \cdot \dots \cdot n_{k+1}$ is $O(len(n')^2)$. Notice first we can do the first $k$ multiplications in $O(len(n)^2)$. Now we multiply $n$ and $n_{k+1}$ to obtain $n'$ which can be done in,
$$len(n)\cdot len(n_{k+1}) \leq len(n') \cdot len(n') = len(n')^2.$$ So combined, the multiplications can be done in $$len(n)^2+len(n')^2 \leq len(n')^2+ len(n')^2 = 2len(n')^2$$ which is $O(len(n')^2)$.